# How to Stop "Auto Input Suggestion" in Android Emulator in Android 2.1 "permanently"

Tags: android-emulator

When I am running my app in Android Emulator and then on providing input through keyboard it displays the auto text in japanese or english and also the fullstop '.' doesn't work.
I made a solution by going through settings->Language&Keyboard option and then disabled the japanese as well as auto keyboard suggestion. But it is only temporary because when running my application another time would auto checked the emulator settings->Language&Keyboard->auto suggestion.

Can anyone give me permanent solution for that.

Thanks in Advance..

Note:
I am running my App through Eclipse.

Comment: One Thing we can do in our Activity that on selecting Edit Text press Escape Button to avoid Android KeyBoard and then long press the mouse left button on that Edit Text. So it will show the Context Menu to Select the input Type, then select "Android Text input" will solve our problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Thing we can do in our Activity that on selecting Edit Text press Escape Button to avoid Android KeyBoard and then long press the mouse left button on that Edit Text. So it will show the Context Menu to Select the input Type, then select Android Text input will solve our problem...